# Change a layout variable value from a page in Nuxt.js

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

There is something I really dont get about Vue / Nuxt, If I import a component in my /blog/slug.vue I am able to change the variables as I want but how I can do that I want to change something in the /layouts/default.vue ? I am able to do it with the  and the  by using **head()** but can I do that with a simple variable like {{ navbar_title }}

For example my /layouts/default.vue look like this :

```
<template>
  <div class="navbar">
    {{ navbar_title }} 
  </div>
</template>
```

Is it possible to can change {{ navbar_title }} value from a page like /pages/about.vue ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please visit code sandbox [link](https://codesandbox.io/s/jolly-cori-3l08v?file=/pages/about.vue)

code

in `NavBar.vue`

```
<template>
  <div>NavBar component  {{ title }}</div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  props: {
    title : {
      type: String,
      required: true,
      default: 'Website title/ suitable title'
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

from page component `pages/index.vue`

```
<template>
  <section>
    <div>
      <NavBar :title="title"/>
      <h2>Starter for CodeSandBox</h2>
    </div>
  </section>
</template>

<script>
import NavBar from '~/components/NavBar.vue'

export default {
  pageTitle: 'from Home Page',
  components: {
    NavBar
  },
  computed: {
    title() {
      return this.$route.matched.map((r) => {
        return r.components.default.options
          ? r.components.default.options.pageTitle
          : r.components.default.pageTitle;
      })[0];
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks but that's not my question, I want to use the same layout and update the title as my need.

Comment: No I mean navbar_title

Comment: @Tahola updated my answer with proper solution code sandbox link  https://codesandbox.io/s/jolly-cori-3l08v
update me if you still have doubts!!

Comment: That's perfect, very helpfull for a beginner, thank you very much !